# MySQL ignore duplicate entries for the same date time

Tags: mysql, laravel-7

I'm working with attendance API, sometimes when the device is offline, the record with the same date will queue on the server API. When the device online, here is the problem, the record will insert at the same time.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$alreadyCheckIn = count($this->attendanceModel
                ->where(DB::raw('DATE(attendance_time)'),'=', $todayDate)
                ->where('employee_id', '=', $employeeId)
                ->where('attendance_type', '=', $attendanceType) //check in
                ->get());

if($alreadyCheckIn <= 0){ //no check in
   $this->attendanceModel->create([
    'attendance_type' => $attendanceType,
    'attendance_time' => $attendanceTime,
    'input_type' => $inputType,
    'employee_id' => $employeeId
   ]);
}
```

I want limit only one entry for the same date. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try setting the column attendance_time as UNIQUE?

Comment: Does it will throw error? How about other employee_id with the same attendance_time?

Comment: Yup it will throw an error. You can also set (employee_id, attendance_time) *together* as unique.